# PHP Getting Wrong ID in Loop

Tags: php

I am fetching products in loop.. there are total Four loop.

- Fist loop fetch main categories
- Second loop fetch their sub categories
- Third loop fetch all the categories form the second level
- Fourth Loop fetch all the product from the third level categories.

```html
<div class="content-page">
    <div class="container">
    
<?php
$main_cats=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TBLCATS inner join TBLCATDETAIL on TBLCATDETAIL.catid=TBLCATS.recid where TBLCATS.parent='0' and TBLCATS.Hidden='No' and TBLCATDETAIL.langid=$LangID ORDER BY TBLCATS.rank") or die("Error getting records For Main Categories");
////FIRST LOOP GETTING MAIN CATEGORIES/////
while($row_main_cat=mysql_fetch_array($main_cats)){
?>    

        <div class="category-featured">
            <nav class="navbar nav-menu bgcolor show-brand">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="#"><?php print $row_main_cat['catname'];?></a></div>
                  <span class="toggle-menu"></span>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">  
<!-- tabing menu start -->         
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <?php
     
$second_level=dbQuery("SELECT * FROM TBLCATS inner join TBLCATDETAIL on TBLCATDETAIL.catid=TBLCATS.recid where TBLCATS.parent='$row_main_cat[recid]' and TBLCATS.Hidden='No' and TBLCATDETAIL.langid='$LangID' ORDER BY TBLCATS.rank limit 4") or die("Error getting records For Sub Categories");
$counter_1=1;
////second LOOP GETTING SUB-CATEGORIES/////FOR TAB-HEADS
while($row_second_level=mysql_fetch_array($second_level)){?><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-k<?php print $row_second_level['recid'];?>-<?php print $counter_1;?>"><?php print $row_second_level['catname'];?></a></li><?php $counter_1++;}?>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- tabing menu close -->  
                </div>
              </div>
             
            </nav>
            
           <div class="product-featured clearfix">
                
                <div class="product-featured-content">
                    <div class="product-featured-list">
                        <div class="tab-container autoheight">
                            <!-- tab product START-->
                             <?php
     
$second_level_2=dbQuery("SELECT * FROM TBLCATS inner join TBLCATDETAIL on TBLCATDETAIL.catid=TBLCATS.recid where TBLCATS.parent='$row_main_cat[recid]' and TBLCATS.Hidden='No' and TBLCATDETAIL.langid='$LangID' ORDER BY TBLCATS.rank limit 4") or die("Error getting records For Sub Categories");
$counter_2=1;
////second LOOP GETTING SUB-CATEGORIES/////FOR TAB-PANEL
while($row_second_level_2=mysql_fetch_array($second_level_2)){?>
                            <!-- tab product -->
                            <div class="tab-panel" id="tab-k<?php print $row_second_level_2['recid'];?>-<?php print $counter_2;?>" dir="ltr">
                                <ul class="product-list owl-carousel"  data-dots="false" data-loop="true" data-nav = "true" data-margin = "0" data-autoplayTimeout="1000" data-autoplayHoverPause = "true" data-responsive='{"0":{"items":1},"600":{"items":3},"1000":{"items":4}}'>
<?php
//GETTING ALL THE THIRD LEVEL CATEGORIES AND FETCH PRODUCST FROM ALL THIRD LEVEL CATEGORIES.
$third_level=dbQuery("SELECT * FROM TBLCATS inner join TBLCATDETAIL on TBLCATDETAIL.catid=TBLCATS.recid where TBLCATS.parent='$row_second_level_2[recid]' and TBLCATS.Hidden='No' and TBLCATDETAIL.langid='$LangID' order by TBLCATS.rank") or die("Error getting records");
$psqlp="";
/// HERE I GET PERFECT NUMBER OF THIRD LEVEL CATEGOIES
print mysql_num_rows($third_level);
while($row_third_level=mysql_fetch_array($third_level))
{
$psqlp.=" or TBLPRODS.catid='$row_third_level[recid]'"; 
}
//HERE IS A PRODUCT QUERY WHERE I PUT ALL THE THIRD LEVEL CATEGORIES ID BUTT IT FETCH ALL THE OTHER NON RELATED PRODUCTS
$kkacprod=dbQuery("SELECT * FROM TBLPRODS inner join TBLPDET where TBLPRODS.recid=TBLPDET.pid and TBLPRODS.Hidden='No' and TBLPRODS.langid='$LangID' $psqlp ORDER by rand() limit 20") or die("Error loading Products");while($krspffs=dbFetchArray($kkacprod)){?> 
                                   <!-- HERE I GET WRONG CAT ID... FOR EXAMPLE MAIN CATEGORY IS MOBILE AND SECOND CATEGORY IS SAMSUNG AND THIRD IS GALAXY BUT HERE I GET OTHER FOR EXAMPLE PRINTERS. -->
                                    <li><?php print $krspffs['recid'];?></li>
                                    
                                    <?php }?>
                                   
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                           
                            <?php $kcnt2++;}?>
                            <!-- tab product END -->
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end featured category jewelry-->
          <?php }?>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrPDv.jpg)

Comment: In your `second_level` query, you have `TBLCATS.parent='$sacrc[recid]'`. That would evaluate to `TBLCATS.parent='SOMETHING[recid]'` which doesn't seem right. Same for the third query. Similar for the 4th query: `TBLCATS.parent='$row_second_level_2[recid]' ` - you'll probably want something like `TBLCATS.parent='{$row_second_level_2['recid']}' `

Comment: i update that now please review the post again and provide any suggestion.

Comment: the final output of this query is mention below.

select * from tblprods where tblprods.Hidden='No' or tblprods.catid='3' or tblprods.catid='4' or tblprods.catid='5' or tblprods.catid='6' limit 20

can you please suggest is it ok ? 

because it fetch products from other categories too.

Comment: Your question doesn't actually ask a question, nor does it provide a clear problem statement, example input, or expected output. Please take the [tour], check out the [help/on-topic], and read [ask], then come back when you have a clear on-topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$psqlp.=" or TBLPRODS.catid='$row_third_level[recid]'";
```

as this constructs a query

```
SELECT ...
WHERE TBLPRODS.recid=TBLPDET.pid 
  AND ...
  AND ...
   OR TBLPRODS.catid = ...
   OR TBLPRODS.catid = ...
```

which is not what you intended. To get only the products in those categories, use

```
WHERE  ... AND TBLPRODS.catid IN (1,2,...)
```

which is another form of

```
WHERE ... AND ( TBLPRODS.catid = 1 OR TBLPRODS.catid = 2 OR ... )
```

---

I've taken the liberty of changing your code so it's a bit more manageable, and I hope it gives you some hints for alternative approaches. I've factored out some `function`s, and used [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and use yet another way to find the products in that category using a subquery. Queries at the bottom. Enjoy.

```
<div class="content-page">
  <div class="container">
    <?php
      foreach ( get_categories( $db, $lang_id, 0 ) as $cat )
        show_main_category( $db, $lang_id, $cat );
    ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php


function show_main_catgory( $db, $cat )
{
  $nav = null;
  $tab = null;
  foreach ( get_categories( $db, $cat->recid, $lang_id, "LIMIT 4" ) as $i => $subcat )
  {
    $html_id = "tab-k{$subcat->recid}-$i";

    $nav .= "<li><a data-toggle='tab' href='#$html_id'>$subcat->catname</a></li>";

    $tab .= "
      <div class='tab-panel' id='$html_id' dir='ltr'>
        <ul class='product-list owl-carousel'>"
        . implode( "\n",
          array_map( function($prod) { return "<li>$p->recid</li>"; },
          get_products_in_child_cats_of( $db, $subcat->recid, $lang_id )
        ) )
        . "
      </ul></div>";
  }

  echo <<<HTML
      <div class="category-featured">

        <nav class="navbar nav-menu bgcolor show-brand">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="#">$cat->catname</a></div>
            <span class="toggle-menu"></span>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <!-- tabing menu start -->
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
                $nav 
              </ul>
              <!-- tabing menu close -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="product-featured clearfix">
          <div class="product-featured-content">
            <div class="product-featured-list">
              <div class="tab-container autoheight">
                <!-- tab product START-->
                $tab
                <!-- tab product END -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
HTML;
}

function db_query( $db, $sql, $args = [] ) {
  $sth = $db->prepare( $sql );
  $sth->execute( $args );
  return $sth->fetchAll( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}

function get_categories( $db, $parent_id, $lang_id, $limit = null )
{
  return db_query( "
      SELECT * FROM TBLCATS
      INNER JOIN TBLCATDETAIL ON TBLCATDETAIL.catid=TBLCATS.recid
      WHERE TBLCATS.parent = ?
        AND TBLCATS.Hidden='No'
        AND TBLCATDETAIL.langid = ?
      ORDER BY TBLCATS.rank
      $limit
    ",
    [ $parent_id, $lang_id ]
  );
}


function get_products_in_child_cats( $db, $parent_id, $lang_id )
{
  return db_query( $db, "
      SELECT * FROM TBLPRODS
      INNER JOIN TBLPDET
      WHERE TBLPRODS.recid=TBLPDET.pid
      AND TBLPRODS.Hidden='No'
      AND TBLPRODS.langid = ?
      AND TBLPRODS.catid IN (
        SELECT recid
        FROM TBLCATS 
        WHERE parent = ?
      )
      ORDER by rand()
      LIMIT 20
    ", [ $lang_id, $parent_id ]
  );
}
```

Note: The `$db` should be initialized like

```
$db = new PDO( "mysql:dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass, [
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
] );
```